# Making all variables in a scope global or importing a module inside another module

Tags: python, module, initialization, global-variables, import

I have a package with two modules in it. One is the `__init__` file, and the other is a separate part of the package. If I try `from mypackage import separatepart`, the code in the `__init__` module is run, which will run unneeded code, slowing down the importing by a lot. The code in separate part won't cause any errors, and so users should be able to directly import it without importing the `__init__` module.

Since I can't figure out a way to do this, I thought I should include a function in the `__init__` file that does everything so nothing would be done directly, but in order to do this, I would need to have any variables set to be global. Is there any way to tell Python that all variables are global in a function, or to not run the `__init__` module?

Comment: First, a "package" contains "modules".  Modules map directly (1 to 1) to files.  I think you have a "package" with two "modules" in it.  "might cause errors on some systems" is vague and confusing.  Why aren't you just using a `try` block?

Comment: @S.Lott You're right. I didn't word that question very well, so sorry if I caused any confusion.

Comment: Don't apologize.  Fix the question, please.  Other people might have this problem.  Please fix the wording and provide the missing details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dthat I know of, there is not way to specify that *all* variables are global but you can import the module while you are in the module. <strike>just make sure that you do it in a function that isn't called at the top level, you are playing with infinite recursion here but a simple use should be safe.</strike>

```
#module.py

foo = bar = 0 # global

def init()
    import module as m

    m.foo = 1
    m.bar = 2 # access to globals
```

<strike>if `init` was called at the top level, then you have infinite recursion but it sounds like the whole point of this is to avoid this code running at the top level, so you should be safe.</strike> Since you want to do this in the `__init__.py` file, just import the top level of the package.

It occurred to me on a walk that there's no problem with recursion here because the top level code will only run once on initial import.

Comment: Perfect! I used `self = __import__(__name__)`.

Comment: @None. glad it works. I probably wouldn't use `self` (for clarity) but whatever floats your boat ;)